# Center of mass of a numpy array, how to make less verbose?

Tags: python, numpy

From what I know of numpy, [it's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559463/why-is-numpy-array-so-slow) to apply an operation to each row of an array one at a time. Broadcasting is clearly the prefered method. Given that, how do I take data with a shape `(N,3)` and translate it to the center of mass? Below is the 'bad method' I'm using. This works, but I suspect it will have a performance hit for large `N`:

```
CM = R.sum(0)/R.shape[0]
for i in xrange(R.shape[0]): R[i,:] -= CM
```

Comment: A bit late, but `scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` might be a relevant function to know...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
R -= R.sum(0) / len(R)
```

instead.  Broadcasting will automatically do The Right Thing.

Comment: So the mistake was trying to shoehorn the `CM` array into the subtraction instead of solving it in one shot?

Comment: @Hooked: You could just as well do `CM = R.sum(0) / len(R); R -= CM`, but I figured the intermediate variable doesn't really help readability.

Answer (score 9):

As you've defined it, you can simplify your center of mass calculation as:

```
R -= R.mean(axis=0)
```

If the different elements of your array have different masses defined in `mass`, I would then use:

```
R -= np.average(R,axis=0,weights=mass)
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html