# writing a function with input of array...'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm a beginner in python. I wrote a function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def crossover(v1,v2):

    N=2
    v1n=np.zeros(shape=(1,N+1))
    v2n=np.zeros(shape=(1,N+1))
    beta=np.random.rand(1)

    v1n[0,0]=(1-beta)*v1[0]+beta*v2[0]
    v1n[0][1]=v1[1]
    v2n[0][0]=(1-beta)*v2[0]+beta*v1[0]
    v2n[0][1]=v2[1]

    return (v1n,v2n)
```

when I want to see crossover([3,4],[7,8]), the following error....:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#82>", line 1, in <module>

    crossover([4,5],[5,4])

  File "C:\Python27\crossover.py", line 11, in crossover

    v1n[0,0]=(1-beta)*v1[0]+beta*v2[0]

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Your code seems to be running on my terminal. Are you sure you that you've provided the exact code you're using?

Comment: Your code runs fine as posted, are you sure you have posted the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine on python 2.7.8 (on my computer). But i suggest your output is bad.
if you run your code you get output:

```
(array([[ 4.91965332, 5. , 0. ]]), array([[ 4.08034668, 4. , 0. ]]))
```

This is actually a tuple with two arrays containing each a list.
you are using numpy for small 'arrays' and that is actually slower than normal list.
numpy is used for hundreds, even thousands of data.

[check this link for more info about numpy speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559463/why-is-numpy-array-so-slow/)

i would suggest you just use list instead.

let me give you an example on how i would have done it without numpy :D

```
import random

v1=[5,4]
v2=[4,5]

# basicly random number from 0 to 1
beta=random.random()

# let's initialize v1n and v2n (:
v1n = [0,0,0]
v2n = [0,0,0]

v1n[0] = (1-beta)*v1[0]+beta*v2[0]
v1n[1] = v1[1]

v2n[0] = (1-beta)*v2[0]+beta*v1[0]
v2n[1]=v2[1]

print("first 3d array:")
print(v1n)

print("second 3d array:")
print(v2n)

print("note that this really is 2d arrays because the 3rd dimension is always zero")
```

Comment: Quick note if you ever need help with python. I am a member of "Python Programming Language" group on Facebook. We answer questions, have competitions and stuff. New members are especially welcome (: